# Change name of WP content > Themes folder

Tags: themes

Is there anyway I can change the theme sources files for my sites in the 'sources' tab of Google's dev tools?  I would like to change it so it says themes/companyname as opposed to themes/wpthemename

Many thanks

Emily

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the name of the theme folder. and inside your theme's style.css change the "Theme Name:" accordingly.

Be aware that you need to activate the "new" theme in the Design Tab.